Can I use haproxy to load balance QUIC/HTTP3 connections without terminating TLS
I have ingress-nginx running on a 3-node k3s cluster. In front of that, I have haproxy running, attached to my public IP and using proxy protocol to send HTTP/S (et al) connections to the cluster, and it works great with HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2. Ingress-nginx manages the TLS termination for HTTPS connections, and haproxy can manage the TCP connections easily enough.
My question is: can I add support for HTTP/3 to this setup? I cannot see any way to do it without moving TLS termination to haproxy, since haproxy would need some mechanism to know where to route incoming UDP packets, and for that to work all the ingress-nginx pods on the cluster would need a place to share that state.
I've searched high and low for a howto on this, and haven't found any that doesn't use haproxy for TLS termination.

haproxy can't proxy UDP traffic (except for HTTP/3 because it knows how to parse the session/stream metadata). If your nginx hosts are co-located, then you won't see much performance difference with HTTP/3 vs HTTP/2

It's that "except for" part that I'm curious about. I haven't read the QUIC wire protocol to know if it's possible to associate it with a TCP stream, which haproxy could forward to the correct ingress-nginx instance as it does today with TCP.
